# Coding a page intentionally vulnerable to command injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, code-injection

I am trying to code a page that is intentionally vulnerable to command injection. This is for a training environment. This is the code I have so far:

```
public ActionResult CommandInjection()
    {
        string domain = Request.QueryString["domain"];
        ViewBag.Domain = domain;

        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("nslookup.exe", domain)
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        };

        var proc = Process.Start(psi);
        string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        ViewBag.Msg = "This page is vulnerable to Command Injection";
        ViewBag.Result = result;

        return View();
    }
```

It seems to work well when it sees a normal request for domain lookup.

However, when it sees a request like so:

`http://localhost:50159/Home/CommandInjection?domain=www.google.com+%26+dir` it returns a blank.

What I was expecting was that it would return the result from the domain lookup followed by the output from the `dir` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that easy to shoot yourself in the foot in this case, but you can, like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c \"nslookup.exe " + domain + "\"")
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing your command directly to the [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) function.  This function bypasses the command-line interpreter, cmd.exe.

If you want cmd.exe to handle things, then pass the entire command (as you would type it) as arguments and use cmd.exe as the process name...

```
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "nslookup.exe " + domain)
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    };
```